# Como manter a janela criada pelo PyQT5 aberta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt-5

Depois de estudar bastante tempo a parte de orientação a objetos comecei a estudar o PyQT5. Fiquei com dúvida no seguinte código:

```
class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title='Hello, world!'
        self.left=10
        self.top=10
        self.width=640
        self.height=480
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
            self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
            self.setGeometry(self.left,self.top,self.width,self.height)
            self.show()
if __name__=='__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex=App()
```

Nesse código a janela q era para ser gerada fica menos de um segundo na tela e já some quando eu rodo o código no PyCharm. No IDE do Python 3.7 ele roda normal. Como eu corrijo isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

está faltando a saida do programa, adicione o `sys.exit(app.exec_())`, assim:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex=App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```